# What's the difference between a web server and a development server?

Tags: node.js, express

So a bit of context - I'm trying to give my create-react-app project a backend using express.

I'm following a tutorial that talks about having two servers working concurrently. This leaves me a bit confused - ***what's the difference between a web and a dev server***, and ***how you can have two servers working simultaneously?***

I think the underlying issue here is that I only have a shallow understanding of what a server actually is: I only understand it as being a process that listens to requests and sends responses.

Cheers

Comment: Better suited for this community: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A dev server is typically an internal web server used for testing and running code in development.  It is a web server.  The counter to a dev server would be a production server which would typically be deployed in some hosting facility with outside access to the production web server from the internet and designed for use by real users or clients/customers.

Comment: you use a dev server for your development environment and webserver for your production environment.  you might set up your dev server to listen to the changes you made you compile them on-the-fly which makes your development a lot faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial most likely refers to the following definitions:

- development server

  - available at `localhost`
  - runs on your local machine (i.e. your PC, virtual box, etc.)
  - intended for local development and testing
- web server

  - available at an IP address or domain
  - runs on a remote server like a cloud server such as Google Cloud / Heroku / Digital Ocean
  - intended for production for your real users

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, this tutorial seems to be talking about 2 separate environments, a production environment (i.e. where the 'real' code that clients/users will use runs), and a development environment (i.e. where code that is currently under testing and not ready for the 'real world' runs).

The reason you want (at least) 2 of them is so you can deploy your code to the dev environment and then test it out, see if it works, how it works, and if it breaks anything, without risking the real server going out, or maybe accidentally wiping your real customer database or something like that. When you deploy to your dev environment and see that everything work as it should and nothing is broken, then you can put that version of the code to run in your real, production environment, and be pretty sure your backend is not gonna go out while you are developing

I may be misunderstanding what the article is saying, but from your description I think that is it

Hope that helps you!